# Simplifying "least squares" slope equation

Tags: regression, least-squares

The slope of the best-fit line using least squares in two dimensions is given by

$$m = \dfrac{\sum\limits^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum\limits^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2}$$

However, I've found [this site](https://kavyaraob.wordpress.com/2015/12/16/algorithm/) which states this equation can be simplified to

$$m = \dfrac{\sum\limits^n x_iy_i - x_i\bar{y}}{\sum\limits^n x_i^2 - x_i\bar{x}}$$

I can't see how to get from the traditional form to this one. Expanding the products in the first form, we get

$$m = \dfrac{\sum\limits^n x_i y_i - x_i\bar{y} - \bar{x}y_i + \bar{x}\bar{y}}{\sum\limits^n x_i^2 - 2x_i\bar{x} + \bar{x}^2}$$

This contains all the terms in the site's formulation, but also others, and I can't possibly see how to simplify them away.

Is that formulation incorrect, it is a simplification for a specific case I haven't realized, or am I just doing this wrong?

Comment: Remember that $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$ are denoting $\frac{\sum x_i}{n}$ and $\frac{\sum y_i}{n}$, respectively.

Comment: @logarithm, thanks for the hint. Yeah, that solved it. Should've thought of that myself. Feel free to write an answer for a free checkmark.